# How to set up 2 UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am looking for a way of having UISwipeGestureRecognizers added to 1 view. One that detects Downward swipes and one for right swipes. I have come across similar questions on SE, however they don't solve my problem.

I currently have

```
 swipeGest = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(respondToSwipe:)];
[swipeGest setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
[swipeGest setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[swipeGest setDelegate:self];
[self.viewAnimation addGestureRecognizer:swipeGest];
```

and

```
    sideSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sideSwipe:)];
[swipeGest setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[swipeGest setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[sideSwipe setDelegate:self];
[self.viewAnimation addGestureRecognizer:sideSwipe];
```

What happens is the second sideSwipe recogniser overrides the first one. I tried using the delegate methods as suggested in another thread but have been unsuccessful. Has anyone successfully done this if? so I would be grateful for a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd and 3rd line of right swipe is using `swipeGest`, it should be `sideSwipe`

Looks like copy paste error.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Don't know how I missed that. you wouldn't believe how long Ive been trying to fix this.

Comment: Ive voted to close as I don't think this will be beneficial to anyone else.